# Right-ray topology: interior, closure and boundary of $I = \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: general-topology

I have the following question:

> Let $\tau : = \left\{ {\left( {a,\infty } \right)|a \in \mathbb{R}} \right\} \cup \left\{ {\emptyset ,\mathbb{R}} \right\}{\text{ }}$; $\tau {\text{ is called the right-ray topology of }}\mathbb{R}.$
>
> ${\text{Find }}{I^o},\bar I{\text{ and }}\partial I{\text{ where }}I = \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q},$ the set of all irrational numbers.
>
> $\begin{gathered}
>   Note:{\text{ Here }}{I^{\text{o}}}{\text{ is the interior of }}I;{\text{ }}\bar I{\text{ is the closure of }}I,{\text{ }} \hfill \\
>   {\text{and }}\partial I{\text{ is the boundary/frontier of }}I. \hfill \\ 
> \end{gathered}$

I have the following:

**Interior:** $\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}{\text{  = }}I \notin \tau$. Now for for all $O \in \tau$, only $\emptyset  \subseteq I = \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$, meaning there are no right-ray subsets in $I$ except $\emptyset$ . 

 Therefore ${I^{\text{o}}} = {\left( {\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}} \right)^{\text{o}}} = \emptyset$.

**Closure:**
$\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}{\text{  = }}I \notin \tau$. Now for for all $O \in \tau$, only $\mathbb{R} \supseteq I = \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$, meaning $\mathbb{R}$ is the only closed superset containing $I$. Therefore:

 $\bar I = \overline {\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}}  = \mathbb{R}$.

It follows that $\partial I = \bar I - {I^o} = \mathbb{R} - \emptyset  = \mathbb{R}$.

Could you please verify my answers?

Comment: To say $I$ is closed is to say that $\mathbb{Q}$ is open. So whay did you restate the fact that $I$ is not open when considering the closure?

Comment: Should it rather be: $\mathbb{R} - I = \mathbb{R} - \left( {\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}} \right) = \mathbb{Q} \notin \tau$. Now for for all $O \in \tau$, only $\mathbb{R} \supseteq I = \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$, meaning $\mathbb{R}$ is the only closed superset containing $I$. Therefore: $\bar I = \overline {\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}}  = \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It seems better to me, though your writing is a little confusing in my opinion. You write $O$ and then disregard that notation. Perhaps write: "The only $O\in \tau$ satisfying $O\supseteq I$ is $O=\mathbb{R}$"? Though it could just be confusing for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $(a, \infty) \subseteq \Bbb P$, where $\Bbb P = \Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ is the set of irrationals. As each such open segment contains (lots of) rationals (e.g. large enough integers, for starters), this cannot hold. The only other candidate open sets inside $\Bbb P$ are $\Bbb R$ (no) or $\emptyset$ (yes) so $\mathbb{P}^\circ=\emptyset$.

The only closed sets of $\tau$ are $(-\infty, a]$, which can never contain the unbounded-above $\Bbb P$, $\emptyset$ and $\Bbb R$, so again by process of elimination, $\overline{\Bbb P}=\Bbb R$.

The boundary being $\Bbb R$ too then follows immediately.

So you're correct.